Why is PdfConverter very slow during the first conversion? How can I slove this problem
I'm using PdfConverter to convert word to pdf.But I find that pdfConverter very slow during the first conversion.Then It gets faster.
The response time of my spring boot application use PdfConverter is roughly 12s -> 300ms -> 300ms. So I guess there are cache in PdfConverter.But I don't find them.The main different time is in PdfConverter#doConvert ->XWPFDocumentVisitor#visitore() visitBodyElements.I don't find cache in this class.Where is the cache.
Here is a demo code you can reporduce this situation.
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();  
XWPFDocument xwpfDocument;  
String resourceLocation = "classpath:template/cadreTemplate-new.docx";  
File template = ResourceUtils.getFile(resourceLocation);  
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(template)) {  
xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);  
}  
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(xwpfDocument, new ByteArrayOutputStream(), options);

my maven dependency
<dependency>  
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>  
    <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-gae</artifactId>  
    <version>2.0.3</version>  
</dependency>


I want to know different word template need to init every time or they only need init once.
how could I init PdfConverter to reduce my first request time in spring  with an elegant way?

I try different way to find different response time.

PdfConverter is part of a very large library.  You're probably just seeing the time to load the module and all of its dependencies.

It may be the JVM startup and/or the JIT compiler.  What if your hosting setup?  E.g. what version of Java, are you using TomEE or another Jakarta EE?  There may be options to do a warmup request, a keep-alive, or AOT compilation.

I'm using java8.spring boot version is 2.7.6. I run this in a spring boot application.Every time I restart my server.First time is slow,then it get faster.This is done by PdfConverter or others?   thanks for your answer.

It's perfectly normal for all Java code to be slow to start up and then get faster.

Sounds normal for first use of huge set of lib dependencies. If you simply wish to avoid having the first user seeing the long delay you might consider generate a small PDF in startup. This moves the delay for an apparent benefit the response time of first accessor (because it is now the 2nd run).

See "Why GraalVM instead of plain ol' Java?" at https://spring.io/blog/2023/09/20/hello-java-21 .  GraalVM native images (ahead-of-time compilation) may allow you to massively decrease startup time.
On an sample app benchmark (Spring Petclinic), they had 34x faster startup speeds.

Image is from https://medium.com/graalvm/graalvm-for-jdk-21-is-here-ee01177dd12d
The benchmarks are for the Oracle build of GraalVM (not necessarily the same as a build of the FOSS version).
